# Is there a way to pass a file source URL or .buffer() into Puppeteer fileChooser without having the file downloaded previously for uploading?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am making a bot to download a bunch of images and then later upload them in .jpg format. I figured that this may take up a lot of space so alternatively I thought about saving the image source URLs into a json file instead and later passing the URL or the .buffer() into the fileChooser.

I am not sure if what I am trying to achieve here is possible at all, so as another alternative I could just always save the images as I need to upload them and then delete them straight away.

I guess the .buffer() wouldn't be a file as well anyways so I doubt I could just pass that in somehow.

Any recommendations or ideas if this is possible?